# Can this post be completely removed?

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, request

I posted this question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82329/inducing-thoughts-with-brain-waves) and mentioned that if this was too off-topic, I would be willing to close it, it was even closed but is still getting downvoted. Could someone delete this post entirely, as I understand that deleting too many of your own posts can create trouble for asking questions in future.

Comment: Well, if you really want it to be deleted, you can wait for 2-3 days or so. Can't you? o_O

Comment: With respect to "deleting too many of your own posts can create trouble": note that it only stems from having too many deleted posts. It doesn't matter whether you are the one who deletes the posts, or someone else. So if you really want a question deleted, you might as well do it yourself; no need to post on meta. (But as Manishearth mentioned, the question ban is not enabled on this site.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

Deleting your own posts only really causes problems if the community feels that they have value. While a closed post can be improved and get reopened, it is OK if you feel that it is unsalvageable and delete it.

Note that on Stack Overflow (and Programmers, Super User, and Server Fault), having too many deleted questions can lead to a question ban. However, this happens even if someone else deletes them. The question ban is not enabled for Physics as we do not have much flooding of substandard questions.

Comment: Thank you for both deleting the post and the knowledge, its a relief to be able to delete your own post :D